# How do I create label which display the product rate when the product is selected from the drop-down using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want  to create the system where once the product is selected from the drop-down the rate of the product should be displayed in the label using ajax in laravel.

This is my ajax code.

```
$('#textbox'+counter).on('change',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
        data:{'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
        $('#rate'+counter).html(data);
        }
    });
    })
$('#textbox1').on('change',function(){
    $value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
        data:{'search':$value},
        success:function(data){
        $('rate1').html(data);
        }
    });
    })
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
```

This is the text box code in javascript.

```
 var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<select class="input" style="width:70%" name="textbox' +counter+'" id="textbox' + counter +'">@foreach($products as $product)<option>{{$product->item_name}}</option>@endforeach</select><input type="number" class="input" id="rate'+counter+'"><input style="width:30%" type="number" class="input" placeholder="Enter the Quantity" name="qty' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" min=0 value="">');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
```

This is the function which finds the rate.

```
 public function rateFind(Request $request)
    {
        $rate=Product::where('item_name','=',$request->search)->pluck('rate')->first();
        return Response($rate);
    }
```

currently I have taken textbox to take value. But it doesn't returning the rate.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have explained here step by step.

Here I used the name of the controller & model just for an example you can replace with your controller & model name

In blade file:

Here I used the static option in the dropdown you can add your dynamic options

```
<select id="products">
    <option value="1">Product-1</option>
    <option value="2">Product-2</option>
    <option value="3">Product-3</option>
</select>

<p id="selected_product_price"></p>
```

In route file: (web.php)

```
Route::post('get-product-price', 'ProductController@product_price');
```

In controller:

```
public function product_price(Request $request){
    $post = $request->all();

    $product = Product::find($post['product_id']);

    return response()->json('product' => $product);
}
```

In js code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#products', function(){

    var baseurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

    var product_id = $(this).val();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: baseurl + "/get-product-price",
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
            product_id: product_id
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) { 
           $(document).find('#selected_product_price').html(response.product.price);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @JaydeepRajgor you can use js code in blade file between <script></script> & add cnd link of jquery top of the blade

Answer (score 0):

we need more information of wich javascript frameworks you use. 
The first idea would be to give the label with a span tag inside wich has an id. Then set a onchange event on the selectbox, wich will loud the price over ajax. After that select the id and change the price. If you use Jquery it you could use $('#id').text(priceLoadedOverAjax)